# Python multiple workers altering the same data

Tags: python, parallel-processing, synchronization, memcached

I have multiple processes that should access the same data. The idea was to use memcache for this. But problem is if p1 reads data and right after that p2 does the same. Now, if p1 stores altered data in mc, when p2 does the same id overrides changes p1 made. If this where in the same process with thread I would use lock. But this could be done by multiple different processes. It could be using java, python, php.
So it seams like memcache is not right choice for this. I need something that will handle locking and everything but to be dead smple key/value storage.
Is there some lib or system for this? How this could be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a bit of creative thinking, you could use Redis to do this. Redis is basically the same as memcache, but supports persistence(which you obvious want to turn off) and lot more datatypes.

You put in data as key-value as before.

When you want to lock, you use a redis set(which cannot have multiple of the same value).

I use redis from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/redis/

A sketchy example

```
import redis
db = redis.StrictRedis()     # This connecteds to the standard redis port on the local machine

isLocked = db.sadd("mylocks", "mykey")
if not isLocked:
   data = db.hget("mydata", "mykey")
   try:
       # do something with data
       # ...
       # Saving the data
       db.hset("mydata", "mykey", data)
   except:
       pass

   # Now to the unlocking part
   db.srem("mylocks", "mykey")
```

Here mydata is a hash with key as lookup and data as value. The mylocks is the set of locks. If for some reason the whole process could crash, you should add a expire statement to it.

www.redis.io for info about redis. Redis works on linux, windows etc. But my experience say faster on linux.

Comment: Actually I found the same thing for memcached here http://amix.dk/blog/post/19386. It's all based on fact that you can't add value to key that already exists in mc. So mc tells you that. Exactly the same as your idea here. Thanks, it looks like it's solution for me.

Comment: Nice a Danish guy like me :) . Just one thing to remember if you do use expire, is to have long enough lock time, because if the lock time is less than the acquiring lock+read data+process data+write data, then you end up overwriting data.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your simplest answer would be to put your data into a database and let the database handle arbitration.

Most databases provide a mechanism for record locking that can be used for exactly this sort of thing as one essential of databases, (other than storing data), is the ability for multiple users to read and write records asynchronously.

Comment: Yes, but I still have the same problem, because all that db do is ensure that writing operation is atomic. But if p1 stores it's changes first, p2 don't know about that change. So, p2 now work on old data and when it write to db it will overrun changes made by p1. If there is a way to lock table on select, so all others wait until this lock is released, and can't even read, it could work. Am I missing something here?